# hide sitemap node from user

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want made sitemapnode, which is admin can view all the node but user can view certain node. The problem is how can i hide certain node from user. I use VB.net with asp

```
  <siteMapNode url="Form\Report.aspx" title="Report"  description="" roles="admin" >
    </siteMapNode>
```

Answer (score 0):

do you have login page? if you have set up a login page, you can create the rules for users. if users logged in the web, then deny users' permission for those pages. In addition, if you use the menu to display the siteMapNode, then open menu task to change view to dynamic.

hope it is helpful.